# WordPress - Ovveride plugin template in theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have plugin that create new post type. Also plugin set single template for it's single page.

```
add_filter( 'single_template', array( &$this, 'register_ipa_product_post_type_single_template' ) );

function register_ipa_product_post_type_single_template( $single_template ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
        $single_template = IPA_PRODUCT_POST_TYPE_TEMPLATE_FOLDER . 'single-product.php';
    }

    return $single_template;
}
```

How i can override single-product.php in my theme.

I don't found any solutions for my question at this site.

Comment: Why not grab the file, put a copy of it in your template folder, and then update the directory linking to it in your code above?

Comment: In case when i will update plugin i will need update link to my template again.

Comment: I thought the above function is in your themes functions file?

Comment: No this is plugin functions. Ore maybe bad practice stored template files inside plugin. I want to write common plugin with product post type, ANd use it in my projects. But if need i want override template in theme.

Answer (score 1):

just filter it a little later than the current function (ps if doing this within a class you need to reference it using array(&$this, 'function'). I left it out as i assume you are using the functions.php or function override....etc

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'register_ipa_product_post_type_single_template', 100 );

function change_temp( $single_template ) {
      global $post;

if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
    $single_template = 'path to your template file';
}

return $single_template;

};
```